# How to fix "member names cannot be the same as their enclosing type" error when using a class indexer?

Tags: c#, .net, indexer

I have a class named `Item` that I use in my project, and wanted to get/set values inside the class by an indexer function.

I created the indexer function and got the subject error. After some research, it seems like the problem is that the indexer is actually a `List.Item`, thus my error. I can change the class to `Item2` and it compiles, but this class is heavily used and I don't want to rename it if possible. Is this resolvable without changing the name of my class? Or do I just need to forget this and use functions to get/set the values instead of the indexer?

Sample of code that will throw this compile time error:

```
public class Item
{
    public object this[string var_name]
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { }
    }
}
```

Comment: likely the type system needs to have `Item` reserved for other languages.

Answer (score 8):

Well, it is possible, but you need some extra work for it. You need to add the [`IndexerName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.runtime.compilerservices.indexernameattribute%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) attribute:

```
public class Item
{
    [System.Runtime.CompilerServices.IndexerName("ItemIndexer")]
    public object this[string var_name]
    {
        get { return null; }
        set { }
    }
}
```